# Eclipse Connection DFS Location

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, localhost

I have problem when eclipse try me hadoop connect to server I get the following error

During An internal error occurred "Connecting to DFS localhost".
org / apache / commons / lang / StringUtils

and hence not let me if I could help correct this error is the appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You might find this link useful : http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-run-mapreduce-programs-using.html#.UYaXKkAW38s

I have tried to explain the procedure there. This is happening because some of the required jars are missing from the eclipse plugin which comes with the hadoop distribution.

HTH